# Trying to pull usernames from Reddit using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

i'm trying to pull usernames off of reddit source code using j soup and then trying to DM them but i cant figure our how to only pull links that say /user. sorry this is really messy.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Document doc;
    try {

        // need http protocol
        doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.reddit.com/new/).get();

        // get page title
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);

        // get all links
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse("https://www.reddit.com/new");
        Elements certainLinks = 
        doc.select("https://www.reddit.com/user"); {

            // get the value from href attribute
            {
                System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
                System.out.println("text : " + link.text());

            }


            catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      }

     }
  }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: sounds like spamming to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smth like this

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.reddit.com/new/").get();
        Elements certainLinks = doc.select("a[href*=https://www.reddit.com/user/]");
        certainLinks.forEach(l -> System.out.println(l.text()));
```

Will print:

```
_serial_chiller
dracorian
ImagesOfNetwork
...
```

`a[href*=https://www.reddit.com/user/]` means all `a` elements with `href` attribute containing `https://www.reddit.com/user/` string